# How to grab an adjacent maps image in google maps static API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps static API to retrieve an image. I'm trying to figure out a way to grab the image that would be directly to the north, essentially the next tile if it were a map. I know it will be based on the zoom, but I really can't figure out where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us your code - in particular what are you using for the 'center' attribute - latlng coordinates or a place name string?

Comment: What is your use case for wanting to do this?

Comment: As of yet I don't have much code, I'm grabbing the image from the static API based on a lat lng (you simply pass it in the url along with the zoom). Basically I need to figure out what the correlation between zoom and distance are.